# Sum $S(n,c) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{i}{ci+(n-i)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, asymptotics

Consider the sum $$S(n,c) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{i}{ci+(n-i)}$$ where $0\le c\le 1$.

When $c=0$, $S(n,c)$ grows asymptotically as $n\log n$.

When $c=1$, $S(n,c)$ grows asymptotically as $n$.

What about when $0<c<1$? Can we calculate $S(n,c)$ exactly? What about asymptotics? Can we find upper/lower bounds?

Comment: The harmonic series grows asymptotic to $\log n-\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, not $n\log n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$S(n;c) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \dfrac{k}{ck+(n-k)} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \dfrac{k/n}{1+(c-1)k/n}$$
Hence,
$$\dfrac{S(n;c)}n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \dfrac{k/n}{1+(c-1)k/n} \dfrac1n \sim \int_0^1 \dfrac{xdx}{1+(c-1)x} = \dfrac{(c-1)-\log(c)}{(c-1)^2} \text{ for }c \in (0,1)$$
Hence,
$$S(n;c) \sim \dfrac{(c-1)-\log(c)}{(c-1)^2} n \text{ for }c \in (0,1)$$
Better approximations can be obtained using [Euler Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
When $c = 1$, $\color{#0000ff}{\large{\rm S}\pars{n,1}} = \braces{\pars{n - 1}\bracks{\pars{n - 1} + 1}/2}/n = \color{#0000ff}{\large\pars{n - 1}/2}$.

Let's consider the case $c \not= 1$:
\begin{align}
{\rm S}\pars{n, c} &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}{i \over ci + \pars{n-i}}
= 
\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}{i \over \pars{c - 1}i  + n}
=
{1 \over c- 1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}{i \over i  + n/\pars{c - 1}}
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over c- 1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}
\bracks{1 - {n/\pars{c - 1} \over i  + n/\pars{c - 1}}}
={n - 1 \over c - 1} - {n \over \pars{c -1}^{2}}\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 2}
{1 \over i + n/\pars{c - 1} + 1}
\\[3mm]&=
{n - 1 \over c - 1} - {n \over \pars{c - 1}^{2}}
\braces{\Psi\pars{\bracks{{n \over c - 1} + 1} + n - 1} - \Psi\pars{{n \over c - 1} + 1}}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\color{#0000ff}{\large{\rm S}\pars{n, c \not= 1}}
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}{i \over ci + \pars{n-i}}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#0000ff}{\large{n \over c - 1} + {n \over \pars{c - 1}^{2}}
\bracks{\Psi\pars{{n \over c - 1}} - \Psi\pars{n\,{c \over c- 1}}}}
\end{align}
$\Psi\pars{z}$ is the $\it digamma$ function and we used the identities:
$$
\Psi\pars{x + m} = \Psi\pars{x} + \sum_{k = 0}^{m - 1}{1 \over x + k}\,,\qquad
\Psi\pars{1 + z} = \Psi\pars{z} + {1 \over z}
$$

> When $0 < c < 1$, the digamma functions arguments go to $-\infty$. It's convenient to use the $\it\mbox{digamma reflexion formula}$:
> $$
> \Psi\pars{z} = \Psi\pars{1 - z} - \pi\cot\pars{\pi z}
> $$
> $$\left\lbrace%
> \begin{array}{rcl}
> \Psi\pars{n \over c - 1}
> & = &
> \Psi\pars{1 + {n \over 1 - c}} + \pi\cot\pars{\pi n \over 1 - c}
> =
> \Psi\pars{n \over 1 - c} + {1 - c \over n} + \pi\cot\pars{\pi n \over 1 - c}
> \\[1mm]
> \Psi\pars{nc \over c - 1}
> & = &
> \Psi\pars{1 + {nc \over 1 - c}} + \pi\cot\pars{\pi nc \over 1 - c}
> =
> \Psi\pars{nc \over 1 - c} + {1 - c \over nc} + \pi\cot\pars{\pi nc \over 1 - c}
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> and
> \begin{align}
> {\rm S}\pars{n,c}
> &=
> -\,{1 \over c\pars{1 - c}}
> \\[3mm]&+ {n \over \pars{c - 1}^{2}}\bracks{%
> \Psi\pars{n \over 1 -c} - \Psi\pars{nc \over 1 - c}
> + \pi\cot\pars{\pi n \over 1 -c} - \pi\cot\pars{\pi nc \over 1 -c}}
> \\[3mm]
> \left.\vphantom{\LARGE A}{\rm S}\pars{n,c}\right\vert_{0\ <\ c\ < 1 \atop n\ \gg\ 1}
> &\sim
> -\,{1 \over c\pars{1 - c}} + {n \over \pars{c - 1}^{2}}\bracks{%
> \ln\pars{1 \over c} + \pi\cot\pars{\pi n \over 1 -c}
> -
> \pi\cot\pars{\pi nc \over 1 -c}}
> \end{align}
> where we used the digamma function $\it\mbox{asymptotic behavior}$:
> $\Psi\pars{z} \sim \ln\pars{z}$ when $\verts{z} \gg 1$. Notice that the $\cot$'s terms are "oscillating ones".

Notice that
$$
\pi\cot\pars{\pi n \over 1 -c} - \pi\cot\pars{\pi nc \over 1 -c}
=
-\,{\pi\sin\pars{n\pi}
    \over \sin\pars{\pi n/\bracks{1 -c}}\sin\pars{\pi nc/\bracks{1 -c}}}
$$
and it vanishes out whenever
$n/\pars{1 - c}\ \mbox{and}\ nc/\pars{1 - c}\ \not\in {\mathbb N}$.

Comment: I think there is an error in the rearrangement $${1 \over c- 1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}
\bracks{1 - {n/\pars{c - 1} \over i  + n/\pars{c - 1}}}
={n - 1 \over c - 1} - {n \over \pars{c -1}^{2}}\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 2}
{1 \over i + n\pars{c - 1} + 1}$$

Comment: @AntonioVargas I just checked the typo. Thanks.

Comment: I'm interested to learn more about this technique, and I'm a little confused.  When $c = 2/3$, say, what is $\Psi\pars{{n \over c - 1}} - \Psi\pars{n\,{c \over c- 1}}$ when $n=1$?

Answer (score -1):

1. There is a closed form, thanks to mathematica (using digammas):

$\frac{c n+n \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{c}{c-1}+\frac{n}{c-1}-\frac{1}{c-1}\right)-n
   \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{n
   c}{c-1}+\frac{c}{c-1}-\frac{1}{c-1}\right)-n}{(c-1)^2}$

1. There are, therefore, asymptotics (also thanks to mathematica), on which MathJax seems to choke, here is a link to the screen grab:
   https://www.evernote.com/shard/s24/sh/e1d1abb1-b8a4-4f4f-bad8-7e476f73f017/7700044225f8b6d0d008346a44a2fc5d

These can be simplified, if one knew the sign of $c,$ but I leave this to you.